# Getting grayscale pixel value at point on UIImage even before and after zoom or pan (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, grayscale

I would like to find the grayscale value of a grayscale UIImage at a given CGPoint as well as doing so when the UIImage has been zoomed and/or panned.

So far I've been able to extract the grayscale values of my entire image using CGContext then finding the grayscale value at point (x,y) in a 1D-array of those grayscale values using the index given by index = x*(width of image) + y. However, I'm unsure how to proceed once I have zoomed in on my image and/or panned it once zoomed.

```
//Converts image to list of grayscale values
func pixelValues(fromCGImage imageRef: CGImage?) -> (pixelValues: [UInt16]?, width: Int, height: Int)
{
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
    var pixelValues: [UInt16]?
    if let imageRef = imageRef {
        width = imageRef.width
        height = imageRef.height
        let bitsPerComponent = imageRef.bitsPerComponent
        let bytesPerRow = imageRef.bytesPerRow
        let totalBytes = height * width

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        var intensities = [UInt16](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)

        let contextRef = CGContext(data: &intensities, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: 0)
        contextRef?.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))

        pixelValues = intensities
    }

    return (pixelValues ,width, height)
}

//Returns grayscale value of image at pixel (x,y)
func getGrayValue(pixelValues: [UInt16], width: Int, x: Int, y: Int) -> UInt16 {
    let i = x*width + y
    return pixelValues[i]
}
```

Comment: This answer might give you some insight on how to proceed when image is zoomed or panned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679983/8447312